# Should I install GPG Suite as root in Mac OS X?

Tags: gnupg

I am learning the command line on Mac OS X and also learning PGP. In [the PGP & GPG book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593270712) it says that I should install GnuPG as root but MacAir has me and always has had as a user on the command line.

Should I learn how to go root on it and install GPG Suite and then use it as a user afterwards, or should I just install the GPG Suite as a user from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I learn how to go root on it and install GPG Suite and then use
>   it as a user afterwards, or should I just install the GPG Suite as a
>   user from the beginning?

Not too sure what that specific book ([“PGP & GPG: Email for the Practical Paranoid” by Michael W Lucas](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593270712)) is saying/advising or the full context. But honestly it seems like those instructions are focused on someone on a Linux machine installing GnuPG from raw source code.

If you are using a packaged Mac OS X installer like the [GPG Suite](https://gpgtools.org/gpgsuite.html) then I wouldn’t really worry about specifics like that. To my knowledge the GPG Suite installs itself as “root” since it needs your administrator password to install. But past that you don’t have to do anything magical or special install it as “root.”